# Sequelize model association update not reflected as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to associate tags to an organization via sequelize's `set<Model>(...)` method and it seems to be setting the tags correctly in the db but the updated org with these new tags does not reflect this.

organization model

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var organization = sequelize.define('organization', {
  ...
  }, {});
  organization.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    organization.hasMany(models.tag)
  };
  return organization;
};
```

tag model

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  ...
  tags.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    tags.belongsTo(models.organization)
  };
  return tags;
};
```

method

```
/**
 * Update organization
 * @param {object} db     - The db handle
 * @param {object} stats  - The datadog client
 */
function updateOrganization(db, stats) {
  return function (req, res) {

    let tagsToAdd = []
    let tagsToDelete = []
    let myOrg

    db.organization.findOne({
      where: {
        id: req.params.id
      },
      include: ['tags', 'users', 'retrievals']
    })
      .then(org => {
        myOrg = org
        return org.getTags()
      })
      .then(tags => {
        let promises = []

        ...a bunch of irrelevant logic

        // Add all the new tags
        tagsToAdd.forEach(tag => {
          promises.push(myOrg.createTag({ name: 'newTag' }))
        })

        return Promise.all(promises)
      })
      .then(updatedOrg => {
        console.log('updatedOrg = ', updatedOrg) <-- Does NOT have tags in updated org output even though they actually exist in db. Why not???
        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(updatedOrg)
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but in the Sequelizejs documentation, they used the setter method for an array of the associated model's create function's return values. So there might be some kind of dependancy there.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm not following.

Comment: While the myOrg.createTag() method creates the tags, it does not set the associations. For that you'll have to call the myOrg.addTag() method and pass the myOrg.createTag() method's return value to it. Which you are not doing in this version of the code. Also In your previous version of the code, you used myOrg.setTags() method to set the associations with the new tags. That method however, according to the documentation, is used with the Tags.create() method's return values passed as an array. So there might be some dependancy between the two method's argument and return values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After countless hours of smashing my skull against anything near me i finally figured out that i needed to call [reload()](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-instances/#reloading-an-instance)

```
.then(updatedOrg => {
  console.log('updatedOrg = ', updatedOrg)
  return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(updatedOrg)
})
```

should be

```
.then(updatedOrg => {
  return myOrg.reload()
})
.then(updatedOrg => {
  return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(updatedOrg)
})
```